# Stop execution of program if user selects invalid file

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, execution

I have a method which reads a file of fixed length. I am trying to provide user with proper validations. So, in the method I included below code.

```
if (currentLine.length() != 257) {
    ViewClass view = new ViewClass();
    ViewClass.invalidFile();
}
```

The method invalidFile() in View class is as follows.

```
public void invalidFile(){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this.rootPane, "Invalid File Selected");        
}
```

I have three files to be uploaded. Once user selects all the files and clicks on generate output, the process of reading the files starts. So, my problem is when user uploads invalid file, the user is shown a message but once user clicks 'Ok' next files are read. Below is the method called on clicking 'Generate Output'.

```
 private void jGenerateOutputBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                   
    Thread execThread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            readFirstFile();
            readSecondFile();
            readThirdFile();
       }
    }
};
execThread.start();
```

I am aiming to stop the program executing further. I included System.exit(0) in the invalidFile() but then the window is closed. I want to hold the window open but stop execution until user selects a valid file.

PS: Please let me know if this is already asked or something that shouldn't be asked here. I didn't find any duplicates. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Throw and catch an exception or use return values that indicate whether to continue or not.

Comment: place a boolean at every upload success.If it fails then i mean boolean value is not changed to true it repeats loop at that point till user uploads correct file try coding that part note that it should not allow the user to enter second file upload until the previous one is true / successful upload

Comment: How user select the files? If using `JFileChooser` then you can filter the files on size basis by setting a custom `FileFilter` and by placing your validation code in `accept()`. In this way invalid file will not be visible to the user.

Comment: Does that restrict the size of file? 
I want the length of each line in the file to be the same not the size of the file

Comment: It depend on the implementation of `public boolean accept(File f)`. You want that file or not. If you want I can provide example code.

Comment: Please provide the example code @m.yadav

Answer (score 0):

make readFirstFile, readSecondFile and readThirdFile to throw an exception when any problem occours, and wrap the call to these methods in a try/catch block. As soon as any of those functions throws an exception, the following functions won't be called

Answer (score 0):

If you make `invalidFile()` throw an exception you can handle it in the prescribed way.

```
public void invalidFile() throws IOException {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this.rootPane, "Invalid File Selected");
    throw new IOException("Invalid file");
}

private void readFirstFile() throws IOException {
    // ...
    invalidFile();
}

private void jGenerateOutputBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    Thread execThread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                readFirstFile();
                readSecondFile();
                readThirdFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Tried this but exception isn't getting caught.

Comment: @NikithaReddy - That is a different problem. Throwing the exception in the inner method is the standard technique.

Answer (score 0):

Below example code will open a `JFileChooser` which will list only those files having a specific file size. [ Note: Depending on the implementation of  `public boolean accept(File f)` of `FileFilter` file's content can be validated but for large files it will have a performance impact.]

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter;

class FileSizeFilter extends FileFilter {

  int size;
  String description;

  public FileSizeFilter(int size, String description) {
    this.size = size;
    this.description = description;
  }

  public FileSizeFilter() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
  }

  @Override
  public boolean accept(File f) {
    if (f.isFile()) {
      long l = f.length();
      // check on size basis
      // or
      // read the file line by line and check the length of line
      if (l == size) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  @Override
  public String getDescription() {
    return description;
  }
}

/**
 */
public class Demo {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Demo");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(400, 400);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    JButton button = new JButton("Select Files");

    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Button clicked");
        JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();

        fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);

        fileChooser.setFileFilter(new FileSizeFilter(257, "File Size Limiter"));
        fileChooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
        fileChooser.showOpenDialog(frame);
        File[] selectedFiles = fileChooser.getSelectedFiles();
        if (selectedFiles != null) {
          for (File file : selectedFiles) {
            System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath() + " : " + file.length());
          }
        }

      }

    });
    frame.add(button);
  }
}
```